# How to select multiple words using touchscreen in win 8

Tags: windows-8, user-interface, touchscreen, highlighting, windows-tabletpc

When I double click on a word, win 8 highlights the word but there are no draggable things to select multiple words like on smartphones. If I touch-hold, i get right-click menu.

I couldn't find anything on google. I'l like to be able to select, for example, "an apple" from "An apple is falling."

I'm using ativ pro 700t with win 8 and chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try touch and drag. Touch the first word ("an" in your example) and immediately drag your finger over untill everything you want is highlighted.

Comment: tried it. doesn't work